# Connect all 3 switches in a 3 gang to be controlled by a single switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light

My kitchen has three light switches (1 main light, 2 under cabinet lights), all in a single box (3 gang). I want to connect them together so that a single switch turns them all on/off at once. Can I wire them as such easily?

Comment: Yes. Probably. But your question is vague and therefore off-topic. Please add details about your current situation to your post.

Comment: You could do this, but why do it? The current set-up is considered to be the superior set up because people will often want to have some of those lights on and others off. Are any of these switches "3-way", that is, is the light also switched by another switch, usually on the other side of the room?

Comment: I usually turn on/off all three at the same time. I also would like to install a Wemo Smart Switch, that way can turn on/off all the lights with one switch and also control it using Amazon Echo.

Comment: You should amend your question to include the plan to add a smart switch. This changes the question significantly and will lead to different answers.

Comment: Why not just use the smart switch on the overhead lights? Do you have a neutral available in this 3-gang box? Does the line feed to all these switches enter into this switch box?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses. @Jim Stewart: My plan is to wire together the two under-cabinet lights and put them on one smart switch, and also make the switch that control the main overhead light as second smart switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

Just pigtail a short piece of wire to the three wires feeding the lights and terminate it on the switched terminal of the switch you want to control them.

Good luck and stay safe!

Comment: This assumes that they're all fed from the same home run, no?

Comment: True but it would be unusual to feed it with two separate circuits. That would be the outlier not the norm.

Comment: Perhaps. Both my recent homes have that situation, though, due to add-on work.